# Page Control not set to middle

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

In my project I am using Horizontal UItableView and UItableviewcell.

It work good.

But the cell not set middle.

I want set the my view like following images.

Note : I am getting this images from the web site.

**Kindly provide any solution or Tutorial Like this**

**1. First View Like this**

[image: First View Like this]

**2. Middle View Like this**

[image: Middle View like this]

**2. Last View Like this**

[image: Final view Like this]

Comment: please try increase height for a cell using delegate method heightforrowatindexpath

Comment: I don't get the problem. It's perfectly centred horizontally. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am already tried this @Vinodh

Comment: We want develop app like this @app_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution from following link.

[Tab Viewer ScrollView](http://code4app.net/ios/Tab-Viewer-ScrollView/4f84fff306f6e75044000002)

An extension of iOS UIScrollView that allows scrolling of multiple pages.